# Resize of math symbols in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to increase the size of the inside circle. Also need to increase box.
How to do these in tikz?

```
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!500] at (14.0,-2) {$\mathlarger{\boxplus}$};
```

Comment: PLease extend your code fragment to an MWE )Minimal Working Example), which we can test as it is. Also please clarify how big should be rectangle.

Comment: Is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz\node [draw, inner sep=4pt, fill=red!50, font=\Huge] {$\boxplus$};
\end{document}`  close to what you after?

Comment: What circle?...

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!50] at (0,0) {\large$\boxplus$};
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!50] at (0,-1) {\Large$\boxplus$};
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!50] at (0,-2) {\LARGE$\boxplus$};
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!50] at (0,-3) {\huge$\boxplus$};
\node [scale=1.125,draw,inner sep=4pt,fill=red!50] at (0,-4) {\Huge$\boxplus$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that `red!500` is the same as `red`, because the number following `!` is a *percentage*, so using a number larger than 100 is useless (you can't get “redder than red”).

[image]